# Sun microsystem is not listed in jprofiler installation process

Tags: jprofiler

i am installing jprofiler and need to provide JVM vendor, version and mode, sun microsystem is not listed there what should I pick instead?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use "Oracle" instead of "Sun Microsystems".